# seleniumRC - where to unpack and have the Java program running from?

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, jar, selenium-rc, ubuntu-12.04

The instruction for seleniumRC say to download the zip file and extract the server "in the desired directory".

For a Linux (Ubuntu) user what is the 'desired directory' to unpack these files into? `/usr/local`? `/bin`? `/lib`? Maybe `/opt`?

I downloaded the zip to my own `~/Downloads` but this doesn't seem like the right place to unpack and have it running in.

Is there a standard or recommended place I should put this Java program into?

Nautilus is not letting me paste it into `/opt` or `/usr` directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, anywhere.  On our Windows CI system, we store it in Subversion at /Tools/selenium/selenium-server/selenium_server.jar and run it from there.  The location doesn't matter.